# ¿Qué función puedo usar para mostrar una nómina de empleados en C?

Tags: c, dev-c++

He usado varias funciones pero no se como implementar la de mostrar una nómina.
En el codigo tengo las funciones de ingresar, eliminar, buscar, sin embargo me gustaria que al registrar a los empleados, estos se muestren como una nómina y es en lo que he estado estancado. Espero me ayuden...soy programador principiante y espero aprender de ustedes.

```
void mostrarMenu(){
    system("cls");
    int opc;
    printf("Seleccione la opcion a realizar: \n1. Mostrar Empleados\n2. Crear 
Empleado\n3. Editar Empleado\n4. Eliminar Empleado\n5. Buscar Empleado\n6. 
Salir\n");
    scanf("%d",&opc);
    fflush(stdin);
```

Este es un intento de lo que quería implementar, no se como hacerlo, solo en esta parte del codigo.

```
void mostrarE(){ 
   system("cls");
   int i=0;
   int numEmp;
   printf("****** NOMINA DE EMPLEADOS******\n");
   getch();
   fflush(stdin);
   if(numEmp>=0){
      printf("Nombre: %s\n",empleado[i].nombre);
      getch();
      fflush(stdin);
      }else{
         printf("No hay Empleados registrados\nPresione una tecla para 
continuar...\n");
        getch();
        fflush(stdin);
    }
}
```

Este es una de las funciones que uso para implementar una de las opciones.

```
void crearE(int i){
   system("cls");
   printf("****** REGISTRO DE NUEVO EMPLEADO ******\n");
   printf("codigo: ");
   scanf("%d",&empleado[i].codigo);
   fflush(stdin);
   printf("Nombre: ");
   gets(empleado[i].nombre);
   fflush(stdin);
   printf("Edad: ");
   scanf("%d",&empleado[i].edad);
   fflush(stdin);
   printf("Cargo: ");
   gets(empleado[i].cargo);
   fflush(stdin);
   printf("Sueldo: ");
scanf("%f",&empleado[i].sueldo);
numEmp++;
printf("Empleado creado con exito!\nPresione una tecla para continuar...");
getch();
}

void eliminarE(){
   int i=0;
   int cod;
   system("cls");
   printf("******ELIMINAR EMPLEADO******\n");
   if(numEmp>=0){
      printf("Ingrese codigo de empleado: ");
      scanf("%d",&cod);
      fflush(stdin);
      i=posStrEmp(cod);
      if(i>=0){
          empleado[i].codigo=0;
          strcpy(empleado[i].nombre,"");
          strcpy(empleado[i].cargo,"");
          empleado[i].edad=0;
          empleado[i].sueldo=0.0;
          numEmp--;
          printf("Empleado eliminado con exito\nPresione una tecla para 
continuar\n");
        getch();
    }else{
        printf("El codigo ingresado no existe\nPresione una tecla para 
continuar...\n");
        getch();
    }
}else{
    printf("No hay empleados para eliminar!\nPresione una tecla para 
continuar...\n");
    getch();
    }
}
```

Comment: `printf("Nómina");`